# Animation during User-control change in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am looking for this:

For example, I have 2 user-controls: uc1.xaml and uc2.xaml and 1 mainwindow in my application. Now, when the application opens mainwindow will show 1st usercontrol i.e uc1. Hence, how to animate to slide effect or any other effect while mainwindow shows uc1. Also, when I click button on uc1, mainwindow switch from uc1 to uc2. I also need to have animation at this step.

Kindly help me with some sample code.

Note: I am using wpf desktop application and it is "NOT" winforms application.

Answer (score 0):

To animate uc1 appearance, you can handle your MainWindow's Loaded event and start any animation from it:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ShowUserControl1().Begin();
    }

    private Storyboard ShowUserControl1()
    {
        // var control1 = new uc1(); uncomment it if the control does not exist

        control1.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform();

        Root.Children.Add(im);
        // Root is your root container. In this case - Grid
        // and you have to add it only in the case if it does not exists

        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

        DoubleAnimation slide = new DoubleAnimation();
        slide.To = 0;
        slide.From = Root.ActualWidth;
        slide.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(400));

        // Set the target of the animation
        Storyboard.SetTarget(slide, control1);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide, new PropertyPath("RenderTransform.(TranslateTransform.X)"));

        // Kick the animation off
        sb.Children.Add(slide);

        return sb;
    }
```

Handle Click event for your button to do the same with uc2.

If you want to hide uc1 and then show uc2 on button click, you have to do something like this:

```
Storyboard sbHideUC1 = HideUserControl1(); //you will have to implement HideUserControl1() that returns Storyboard
sbHideUC1.Completed += (s, e) =>
{
    var sbShowUC2 = ShowUserControl2(); // you will have to implement ShowUserControl2() that returns Storyboard
    sbShowUC2.Begin();
}
sbHideUC1.Begin();
```

Comment: I am using wpf, It would have been great if xaml code was given. I am just expecting storyboard xaml part for slide.

Comment: So you have to store your Storyboards in window's resources and run it with EventTriggers. Handle the same events (Loaded for Window and Click for button) with EventTrigger. http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0290__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/WindowLoadasAnimationTrigger.htm here's example.